# How to add and display reCAPTCHA in password protected form?

Tags: custom-post-types

In a custom post type that is protected, I'm password protecting the post via WordPress' native functionality. Looking for a native solution to add and display reCAPTCHA in password protected form, but a plugin solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the `the_password_form` filter to add or modify the post password form to incorporate the needed markup for Google ReCaptcha. After that, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to enqueue the ReCaptcha Javascript.

Comment: I see okay thanks. But what about displaying error message in the password form but no page refresh when submitting the form just only thru ajax with the error message? Any idea with that?